# How to have "Manage Databases" button in Odoo 11 Enterprise only for selected accounts?

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-11, odoo-enterprise

[image]

I have self-hosted Odoo Enterprise. I want, so that, button to “Manage Databases” is not available for users to access.

The ideal case scenario would be, for only selected accounts, to have access to manage databases.

The default settings let all whoever has the URL to edit and manage the database.

How can I hide “Manage Databases” button so that only selected users have access to the button?

Comment: But even if your users can access it they need master password to do any operation

Comment: God right I just need to setup Master Password actually. That is what I need. Mind to post below?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Remove `Manage Databases` link from the login page.
2. Create a new menu under Settings menu with action of `ir.actions.act_url`.
3. Assign a group to the menuitem.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But he needs to create a database for that and he should do this for all of his databases.